# Missing build.xml error in Hybris installation

Tags: gradle, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to install Hybris 6.6. I am getting the following error(s) while trying to execute:

```
install.bat -r b2c_acc_plus
```

The error I am getting is:

```
c:\Practice\installer>install.bat -r b2c_acc_plus
Java version: 1.8.0_152
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_3c3xvl01rtn1sabh2yuajgw9g.run(C:\Practice\installer\recipes\b2c_acc_plus\build.gradle:124)
:recipes/b2c_acc_plus:setup
Executing: createConfig...
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
Could not execute createConfig ant target
:recipes/b2c_acc_plus:setup FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Practice\installer\recipes\b2c_acc_plus\build.gradle' line: 128

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':recipes/b2c_acc_plus:setup'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Practice\hybris\config\local.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.798 secs
Problem with java process - finished with non-zero exit code (1)
```

I tried finding the location where I have to put build.xml, I could not find the same either.

While trying to install with **b2c_acc** recipe, the setup throws the same error. Nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

A solution has been added. Thanks to all those who helped. :)

Comment: Did you extract whole Commerce Suite package to `C:\Practice`? Please verify that file `C:\Practice\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml` exists.

Comment: Yes, I did; it did not work. However, I settled for ant modulegen. It solves my needs. Thanks a lot, @agabrys

Comment: If you solved the problem, please add an answer and accept it. It can help other users who have similar problems.

Comment: @agabrys I did. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there is another way to get it done.

You can go to `%hybris_home_dir%/hybris/bin/platform`
run

`ant clean all`

there, followed by

`ant modulegen`.